# Class object of generic class (java)

Tags: java, generics

is there a way in java to get an instance of something like `Class<List<Object>>` ?

Answer (score 78):

how about

```
(Class<List<Object>>)(Class<?>)List.class
```

Comment: I like that idea. It causes unchecked cast warning, but it can be easily ignored I guess. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This is brilliant.  Exaclty what I needed to solve a difficult generics problem today.

Comment: Is `(Class<?>)` really needed ? In my tests it seems like `(Class<List<Object>>)List.class` is enough.

Comment: @alarive: `List.class` has type `Class<List>`. A cast from `Class<List>` to `Class<List<Object>>` was illegal (because no type could possibly be a subtype of both) the last time I checked

Comment: This didn't work in my case ("The type List is not generic"), but `(Class<ArrayList<Object>>) (Class<?>) List.class` did.

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic: If you get "The type List is not generic", you have the wrong "List" type (probably the class `java.awt.List` instead of the interface `java.util.List`). Check your imports.

Comment: This question was asked in 2009 and I still see no proper solution even today in 2022... shame on Java!

Answer (score 36):

```
public final class ClassUtil {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> Class<T> castClass(Class<?> aClass) {
        return (Class<T>)aClass;
    }
}
```

Now you call:

```
Class<List<Object>> clazz = ClassUtil.<List<Object>>castClass(List.class);
```

Comment: Not a bad idea. This is basically the same as doing `(Class<List<Object>>)(Class<?>)List.class` but if you need several class objects, you will only have one unchecked cast inside the ClassUtil.

Comment: I like it, because you do not create new objects. Cool. Thanks.

Comment: To provide some type safety, you could require the parameter to be `super` of T.
`public static <T> Class<T> castClass(Class<? super T> aClass)`

Answer (score 10):

Because of type erasure, at the Class level, all List interfaces are the same. They are only different at compile time. So you can have `Class<List>` as a type, where `List.class` is of that type, but you can't get more specific than that because they aren't seperate classes, just type declarations that are erased by the compiler into explicit casts.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in other answers, `Class` represents an erased type. To represent something like `ArrayList<Object>`, you want a `Type`. An easy way of getting that is:

```
new ArrayList<Object>() {}.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()
```

The generic type APIs introduced in 1.5 are relatively easy to find your way around.

Comment: bizarre... no way to do this w/o creating an object?

Comment: Not only creating a new object, a new class (in this case an anonymous inner class). But that example should be new ArrayList, no? Making an anonymous list would require you to implement all the methods.

Comment: Yishai: Erm yes. And it's getGenericSuperclass not getGenericSupertype. And then there's the issue of implementing multiple interfaces.

Comment: Jason S: One object who cares? There's ways of doing it without the new, but you are using plenty of memory for code.

Comment: But you still have to do an unchecked conversion here

Answer (score 2):

You could use Jackson's `ObjectMapper`

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
CollectionType listType = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, ElementClass.class)
```

No unchecked warnings, no empty List instances floating around.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a class object for the List type using:

```
Class.forName("java.util.List")
```

or

```
List.class
```

But because java generics are implemented using [erasures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) you cannot get a specialised object for each specific class.

Answer (score 0):

```
List.class
```

the specific type of generics is "erased" at compile time.