# Retrieving the Class object of the generic argument

Tags: java, generics

I am not sure if this is a duplicate question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079279/class-object-of-generic-class-java) mainly because I'm a bit new to generics, so please be forgiving.

I have a generic class:

```
public class MyGeneric<T extends Collection>
{
    private Class<T> genericType;

    public MyGeneric()
    {
        // Missing code here
    }
}
```

My question is this: how do I initialize the `genericType` attribute? Basically, I need `genericType` to receive the `Class` object of whatever `T` is. If `T` is a `LinkedList`, I would like `genericType` to be equal to `LinkedList.class`.

Is this at all possible? Nothing I try seems to work.

Thanks,
Isaac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably not going to like the answer, but you *must* pass it in yourself.  So your constructor should be declared:

```
public MyGeneric(Class<T> genericType)
{
    this.genericType = genericType;
}
```

Due to type-erasure, the information is not available without being explicit like this.

Comment: Yeah I was starting to suspect that type-erasure may have something to do with it... Another set of eyes helped. Thanks!