# How to return parametrised List<T> in Interface RequestSpecification?

Tags: java, rest

When I do `get` request with Interface `RequestSpecification` and I want return a parametrized `List<T>`, what I must do in method `.as()`??? It is highlight bold! 
Maybe I must to specify one of the implementations of list? but i need specific parametrized `List`!

```
List<> response = given().parameter(x,x)
                   .expect()
                   .statuscode(200)
                   .when()
                   .get("some kind of GET")
                   **.as(List<>.class)**
```

Comment: You could only have `.as(Class<T> klazz)`; one result

Comment: What `RequestSpecification` are you talking about? Because I can't find one that has anything resembling what you're trying to do. `get()` returns a `Response` and there's no such method as `as()`

Comment: See here [link](http://rest-assured.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.4.5/apidocs/index.html?com/jayway/restassured/specification/package-use.html), when you do GET and want to return object and cast him to needed clazz!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class object of generic class (java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079279/class-object-of-generic-class-java)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to type erasure. All lists are the same at runtime. Unless you have the type information of the parameter type as a class object, all you can do is:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<DesiredType> response = (List<DesiredType>)given().parameter(x,x)
               .expect()
               .statuscode(200)
               .when()
               .get("some kind of GET")
               .as(List.class);
```

Be aware though that if this puts in objects that are not of type `DesiredType`, you will encounter problems when accessing that list later on.

Comment: It's doesn't help, there is unmarshal exception! When JAXB parse XML to Java object? May be somethink else?

Answer (score 0):

Due to [**type erasure**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), you can't have `List<String>.class` because that's actually the same as `List<Integer>.class`, `List<Dog>.class`, and `List.class` at runtime.

You could *cast* your list to a `List<T>`, but this is very dangerous (and as such you will get a warning). (See [Jan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16547262/732016).)