# how to instantiate T type inside a template class

Tags: java, oop

I have an abstract class `abstract class MathFunc` that is used to implement the mathematical functions Rastrigin, Griewangk and Rosenbrock in their specific classes `final class Rastrigin extends MathFunc`,  `final class Griewangk extends MathFunc` and `final class Rosenbrock extends MatjFunc`.

This hierarchy of classes and how they are defined so far works flawlessly so I think there is no need to look for improvements on this area.

Now i have to implement another class `Generation` that will have some `ArrayLists` in it but the thing is I need to have a Generation implementation for each mathematical function described above. 
So that i need something like :

```
ArrayList<Rastrigin> rast = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Griewangk> grie = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Rosenbrock> rose = new ArrayList<>();
```

Inside these lists I have some Rastrigin/Griewangk/Rosenbrock objects that I need to instantiate.

I know from the past projects in C++ that I can use templates to specify a generic data type and I'm thinking that this is my solution. My implementation so far looks like this :

```
public class Generation <MathFunc> {
    private final ArrayList<MathFunc> pop = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<MathFunc> nextpop = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<MathFunc> Crossover = new ArrayList<>();

    Generation(MathFunc tp)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < PopSize; i++)
        {
            pop.add(tp);
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is: can i use the abstract class to instantiate the objects that rely on it ? Is there another way to do it ? I'm quite confused about the usage of templates.

But doing `Generation(Mathfunc tp)` seems a little weird to me since abstract classes are not instantiable.

P.S. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079279/class-object-of-generic-class-java) seems like a possible solution but i'm very not sure about it or how it actually works.

Comment: Do you want to use multiple instances of the same `MathFunc` subclass? Or is it correct to add the same instance (`tp`) to the list multiple times?

Comment: @Thomas I want to add in the list in Generation 10 objects of types Rastrigin or 10 objects of type Rosenbrock etc, but i don't know how to instantiate them.

Comment: @Thomas please review the comment on your answer and provide some explanations for the Factory pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reuse the same instance of a `MathFunc` I don't see any major flaws in your code (except that the generic definition of `Generation` should be `Generation<T extends MathFunc`).

So first change your class like this:

```
public class Generation <T extends MathFunc> {
  private final ArrayList<T> pop = new ArrayList<>();
  private final ArrayList<T> nextpop = new ArrayList<>();
  private final ArrayList<T> Crossover = new ArrayList<>();

  Generation(T tp)  {
    for(int i = 0; i < PopSize; i++) {
        pop.add(tp);
    }
  }
}
```

Then instantiate `Generation` like this:

```
Generation<Rastrigin> rastriginGen = new Generation<>(new Rastrigin());
Generation<Griewangk> griewangkGen = new Generation<>(new Griewangk());
Generation<Rosenbrock> rosenbrockGen = new Generation<>(new Rosenbrock());
```

If you want to use multiple instances of a `MathFunc` inside `Generation` you might want to use a factory pattern instead.

Factory interface:

```
interface MathFuncFuncFactory<T extends MathFunc> {
  T createFunc();
}
```

Then add implementations like `RastriginFactory implements MathFuncFuncFactory<Rastrigin>` etc.

Inside Generation:

```
Generation(MathFuncFactory<T> factory) {
  for(int i = 0; i < PopSize; i++) {
        pop.add(factory.createFunc());
    }
}
```

Constructor call:

```
Generation<Rastrigin> rastriginGen = new Generation<>(new RastriginFactory());
```

Comment: I really love this answer thanks a lot will try both of the solutions! I really forgot about Factory pattern.

Comment: Something appears to be wrong with the `public interface MathFuncFactory <T extends MathFunc>() {
       T createFunc();
}` The error appears around <T extends MathFunc()> Please tell me how can i fix it.