# Factory pattern generic interface with type that extends an abstract class

Tags: java, oop, factory-pattern

Okay, I hope I don't try to achieve the impossible here.

I have an abstract class `abstract class MathFunc` that is used to implement the mathematical functions Rastrigin, Griewangk and Rosenbrock in their specific classes `final class Rastrigin extends MathFunc`,  `final class Griewangk extends MathFunc` and `final class Rosenbrock extends MatjFunc`.

I need a Generation class that contains an ArrayList that have to contain several objects of types Rastrigin/Griewangk/Rosenbrock. These objects should be instantiated separately from each other because Rastrigin/Griewangk/Rosenbrock generate in their constructor random numbers that are supposed to remain random.

From my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515026/how-to-instantiate-t-type-inside-a-template-class) I managed to implement a version that starts out fully initialized but has the same Rastrigin (for example) object repeated through the ArrayList. From the answer given there I understand that I should use the Factory pattern to instantiate every object separately. From the answer I have this chunk of code:

```
interface MathFuncFactory <T extends MathFunc()>{
       T createFunc();
}
```

But it doesn't work. How can I implement this design properly and make it work the way I wish? Also would it be possible to instantiate an object of type T inside my Generation class ? I'm a newbie in java so detailed explanations are very appreciated.

p.s. I made this second answer because it is not very related to the initial question which was the usage of generic classes in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't instantiate type parameters like `T` directly. Instead you want `Generation` to accept a factory, so that you can create a new instance in each iteration of the loop:

```
interface MathFuncFactory<T extends MathFunc> {
    T create();
}

class Generation<T extends MathFunc> {

    Generation(MathFuncFactory<T> factory) {
        for (...) {
            list.add(factory.create());
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could create a `Generation` for a particular function as follows:

```
new Generation(new MathFuncFactory<Rastrigin>() {
    public Rastrigin create() {
        return new Rastrigin();
    }
});
```

It might be beneficial to have a class that will make these factories:

```
class MathFuncs {

    private MathFuncs() {}

    static MathFuncFactory<Rastrigin> rastrigin() {
        return new MathFuncFactory<Rastrigin>() {
            public Rastrigin create() {
                return new Rastrigin();
            }
        }
    }

    static Generation<Rastrigin> rastriginGeneration() {
        return new Generation<Rastrigin>(rastrigin());
    }
}
```

so you can simply call

```
new Generation(MathFuncs.rastrigin())
```

or just

```
MathFuncs.rastriginGeneration()
```

Comment: Indeed I was so wrong with the abstract forgotten there. My question would be: using the class `MathFuncs()` can I instantiate new Rastrigin objects inside Generation ?

Comment: Also `return new MathFuncFactory()` throws an error because it says it's anonymous

Comment: What you want to do is give `Generation` a way to instantiate new `Rastrigin` objects, and that way is a `MathFuncFactory`. So, you pass a factory to `Generation`'s constructor, and then `Generation` calls `create()` on that factory, which in turn actually instantiates the new `Rastrigin`.

Comment: I understand but what about that error ? And could you please provide a way to instantiate the Generation in `main`?

Comment: I fixed a few syntax errors. Take a look in particular at the call to `new Generation(new MathFuncFactory<Rastrigin>() { ... }` in my answer.

Comment: If I have two different constructors (one with a parameter one without a parameter) for `Rastrigin`, do i need another representative static function in `MathFuncs` class ?

Comment: That's probably what I would do. FYI, for that method, you'll need to make the parameter `final` so it can be used within the anonymous `MathFuncFactory` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You have two mistakes in your code:

1) You don't need `()` after `extends MathFunc`

2) `abstract` methods should be also marked with the `abstract` keyword

```
abstract class MathFuncFactory <T extends MathFunc> {
    abstract T createFunc();
}
```

Relating to the answer you've linked, you don't need the `abstract` keyword for interfaces:

```
interface MathFuncFuncFactory<T extends MathFunc> {
    T createFunc();
}
```

Comment: Indeed I was mistaken with that abstract but Kelsey Francis provided exact methods for this design pattern that seems to doom my thoughts.