# Getting the class of List<T>

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, generics, collections

Please consider the following 3 Java classes:

Super class:

```
public abstract class Column<T>
{

    private final Class<T> type;
    private final String name;


    public Column(Class<T> type, String name)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Class<T> getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    // ...

}
```

Working subclass:

```
public class FloatColumn extends Column<Float>
{   

    public FloatColumn(String name)
    {
        super(Float.class, name);
    }

    // ...

}
```

Problematic subclass:

```
public class ListColumn<L extends List<T>, T> extends Column<L>
{   

    public ListColumn(String name)
    {
        super((Class<L>) List.class, name);
    }

    // ...

}
```

The problematic subclass (`ListColumn`) compiles fine in Eclipse, with Java compiler compliance set to 1.6. However, when compiled through Maven (using the JDK compiler, with source and target set to 1.6), I get an `Inconvertible types` error at the `super()` call in the  `ListColumn` constructor.

**Edit:** Eclipse does warn about this line (`Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class<List> to Class<L>`).

I know that Eclipse does not use the JDL compiler, and apparently the compiler it does use is less strict than the JDK one.

However, my question is how can I make this code work on the 1.6 JDK compiler.

In other words, how can a I call the super constructor with an argument that conforms to the expected `Class<L>` type where `L` is restricted to `extends List<T>`.

Preferably I only want to make changes in the  `ListColumn` constructor, not in the `Column` class.

Comment: Look at this line for WARNING `super((Class<L>) List.class, name);`

Comment: I don't get a warning at that line (at least not in eclipse). I get a compilation error at it instead. Do you know what I should change in the code?

Comment: I am getting *Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class<List> to Class<L>* in Eclipse.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I didn't see the warning because I had `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on the constructor.

Comment: Try with `super((Class<L>)(Class<?>)List.class, name);`. It also shows the WARNING but you can ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help you.

```
super((Class<L>)(Class<?>)List.class, name);
```

**Note:** It shows WARNING but you can suppress it using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

---

For more info have a look at [Class object of generic class (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079279/class-object-of-generic-class-java)

Comment: Don't you sense a code smell in forcing the compiler to accept `List.class` as a `Class<ArrayList>` or `Class<LinkedList>` ? I agree there are a few cases where you need to trick the compiler as it's too dumb to figure it out; but this is certainly *not* one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Assume I instantiate your class as follows:

```
ListColumn<ArrayList<String>, String> listColumn = new ListColumn<ArrayList<String>, String>("column");
```

Now, your code will try to cast `List.class` to a `Class<ArrayList>` which is not the case.

You can make use of covariance in your `Column` class if you want to allow clients to use subtypes of your `T` generic type. For instance, changing the `Column` constructor to:

```
public Column(Class<? extends T> type, String name)
```

would allow you to call super in your `ListColumn` without any cast, since any subtype of `List` would now be allowed, but in a *type safe* manner.

As for tricking the compiler to accept any sort of generics cast with a mere warning, you can use the most dirty "double cast" trick that simply eliminates generics so the compiler won't catch up with your code anymore:

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<String> s = (List<String>) (List) l;
```

But is that really what you want ?

Comment: `new ListColumn<>` is a JAVA 7 syntex. OP is asking *However, my question is how can I make this code work on the 1.6 JDK compiler*