# How to pass parameter with generic: Class<Clazz<G>>

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, generic-programming

I try to parse a XML(String) to a Object using JAXB, but I can't find the way to call the method I had created because I don't know how to specify the class `BasicRequest<G>` with the `SomeRequest` as `G`

```
public class XMLParser {

    public <G extends BaseRequest> BasicRequest<G> xmlToRequest(String xml, 
            Class<BasicRequest<G>> t) {
        BasicRequest<G> request = null;
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.instance(t);
            Unmarshaller m = context.createUnmarshaller();
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
            JAXBElement<BasicRequest<G>> unmarshal = m.unmarshal(new 
                StreamSource(reader), t);
            request = unmarshal.getValue();
        } catch (JAXBException ex) {
            //write log
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

This are my classes:

```
public abstract class BaseRequest {
    protected String version;

    //getter & setter
}
```

,

```
public class SomeRequest extends BaseRequest {
    protected Integer id;

    //getter & setter
}
```

and

```
public class BasicRequest<G extends BaseRequest> {
    protected String user;
    protected G data;

    //getter & setter
}
```

All classes actually have the JAXB annotation correctly.

If someone could please give me a hand on how should I call the method or a better way to define it I would appreciate.

Comment: What error and/or output are you seeing?

Comment: Basically to call this method I had to pass the class definition something like that `Class<BasicRequest<SomeRequest>>`, but I cannot instantiate it and obviously didn't work if I try `BasicRequest<SomeRequest>.class`. I will try the Sumitsu answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps someone better-versed in JAXB has a clever JAXB-centric solution, but from the standpoint of generics, I do not believe there is a way to do what you are trying to do. The type parameter information for the enclosing `BasicRequest` class is erased at runtime (see [Class object of generic class (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079279/class-object-of-generic-class-java)), so any `Class` object representing a `BasicRequest` will simply reflect the raw type. (Correspondingly, the `Unmarshaller` will have no way to know what that parameter is intended to be.)

You could try one of the following solutions:

1. If you are certain that what the Unmarshaller returns will conform to BasicRequest, then you could cast the result to `JAXBElement<BasicRequest<G>>`. The cast will produce an unchecked cast warning (again, because of type erasure), which can be suppressed with the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation on the enclosing method, if you wish.
2. For each class you have which could take the place of G, you could create a subclass which extends BasicRequest parameterized with that class, i.e.:

   ```
   public class SomeBasicRequest extends BasicRequest<SomeRequest> {
   ...
   }
   ```

   `SomeBasicRequest` would not be assignable from `Class<BasicRequest<G>>`, though, so you'd have to change the method header as follows:

   ```
   public <G extends BaseRequest> BasicRequest<G> xmlToRequest(String xml, Class<? extends BasicRequest<G>> t) {
   ...
   }
   ```