# How can I generate a JSON Schema from a Java class with generics when I am only given a string?

Tags: java, json, generics, jackson, type-erasure

I am working on a project where I need to generate JSON schemas for all of the objects that are returned from my API.

I am given a String such as:

`"com.example.CustomListing<MyClass>"`

My goal is to create a schema for `CustomListing` and insert a `$ref` to `MyClass` in all the places it is used in `CustomListing`.

Jackson offers a way to create schemas from generics [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind#3-minute-tutorial-generic-collections-tree-model) but I need to have Class object for that generic type.

I can create a generic Class object using a method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5756536/2193387) but it requires me to know the type ahead of time, which I do not.

**How can I get a `Class<CustomListing<MyClass>>` when I am only given the String `"com.example.CustomListing<MyClass>"`?**

---

EDIT: I am creating these schemas in a JavaDoc doclet, so I am working at compile time, hence the limitations.

Comment: There is no such thing as `Class<CustomListing<MyClass>>`.

Comment: Generics are a compile time concept. There is (almost) no point to know the generic type argument a runtime and it will not help here.

Comment: I updated my question. I am working in a javadoc doclet. I am creating a documentation engine that needs to document the JSON schema for those generic types, so I can't just ignore them.

Comment: Sure but you want to use the `Class` object with Jackson at runtime. You probably want a `TypeReference`, but I'm not exactly sure what you are working with.

Comment: @Vidia Java Doclet has the API to access the type parameters. Have you tried at it?

Comment: That is how I am getting the string. 
And I have seen the TypeReference but I need to set the Generics of that dynamically, which is what I am asking about.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a direction to go for the solution. I am using `ObjectMapper` from Jackson which allows me to configure modules to process any given type. I believe I can register some to deal with a generic (such as `<T>`) and it would know that in this case `<T>` would be referencing `MyClass` instead and insert the `$ref`.