# Generic Class Enum Return type

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have defined a converter interface and a couple converters:

```
public interface StringConverter<T> {
  T convert(String value);
}

public class EnumConverter<E extends Enum<E>> implements StringConverter<E>{

  private final Class<E> enumClass;

  public EnumConverter(Class<E> enumClass) {
    this.enumClass = enumClass;
  }

  @Override
  public E convert(String value) {
    return Enum.valueOf(enumClass, value);
  }
}

public class IntegerConverter implements StringConverter<Integer> {

  public Integer convert(String value) {
    return Integer.parseInt(value);
  }

}
```

I have created a factory interface that returns StringConverter classes.

```
public interface StringConverterClassFactory {
  <T> Class<? extends StringConverter<T>> getConverter(Class<T> forType);
}
```

I'm having trouble with the StringConverterClassFactory implementation.

```
public class DefaultConverterClassFactory implements StringConverterClassFactory {

  @Override
  public <T> Class<? extends StringConverter<T>> getConverter(Class<T> forType) {
    if(forType.equals(int.class) || forType.equals(Integer.class))
      return (Class<? extends StringConverter<T>>)IntegerConverter.class;
    else if(forType.isEnum())
      return (Class<? extends StringConverter<T>>)EnumConverter.class;
    else
      return null;
  }
}
```

Results in compile errors for both converters i.e. `incompatible types: Class<IntegerConverter> cannot be converted to Class<? extends StringConverter<T>>`.

Using raw types I can get rid of the IntegerConverter compile error, but I still get the same error for EnumConverter. `error: incompatible types: Class<EnumConverter> cannot be converted to Class<? extends StringConverter<?>>`

```
public class DefaultConverterFactory implements StringConverterClassFactory {

  @Override
  public Class<? extends StringConverter<?>> getConverter(Class forType) {
    if(forType.equals(int.class) || forType.equals(Integer.class))
      return IntegerConverter.class;
    else if(forType.isEnum())
      return (Class<? extends StringConverter<?>>) EnumConverter.class;
    else
      return null;
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do something like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public <T> Class<? extends StringConverter<T>> getConverter(Class<T> forType) {
    if (forType.equals(int.class) || forType.equals(Integer.class)) {
        return (Class) IntegerConverter.class;
    } else if (forType.isEnum()) {
        return (Class) EnumConverter.class;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. Can you explain why EnumConverter.class is incompatible with (Class<? extends StringConverter<?>>), (Class<? extends StringConverter<T>>), and (Class<? extends StringConverter<T extends Enum<T>>>)?

Comment: I found this while looking around for something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079279/class-object-of-generic-class-java

Comment: @BrandonJohnson: `EnumConverter.class` has type `Class<EnumConverter>`, which is not a subtype of `Class<? extends StringConverter<?>>` because `EnumConverter` is not a subtype of `StringConverter<?>`. And the reason for that is that `EnumConverter` is a generic type; using its raw type turns off all generics, including generics in its inheritance. You can say that `EnumConverter<?>` is a subtype of `StringConverter<?>`, or that `EnumConverter` is a subtype of `StringConverter`, but not that `EnumConverter` is a subtype of `StringConverter<?>`.

Answer (score 0):

Both `<T>` and `<?>` are redundent!

Just write like this:

```
    @Override
    public Class<? extends StringConverter> getConverter(Class forType) {
        if (forType.equals(int.class) || forType.equals(Integer.class)) {
            return IntegerConverter.class;
        } else if (forType.isEnum()) {
            return EnumConverter.class;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

I have not seen this issue before, so i donot really know the reason. Here is my guess:

- `<T>` is not a actual Type,so error will occur as long as cast to `Class<? extends StringConverter<T>>`, like `Class<IntegerConverter> cannot be converted to Class<? extends StringConverter<T>>`.
- `IntegerConverter` implements with actual Type `<Integer>`, so `(Class<? extends StringConverter<Integer>>) IntegerConverter.class` will be correct, and `(Class<? extends StringConverter<?>>) IntegerConverter.class` also works.
- `EnumConverter` implements with generic Type `<E extend Enum<E>>`, so `EnumConverter.class` cannot cast to any form with a Type: `Class<? extends StringConverter<T>>` or `Class<? extends StringConverter<?>>`.

  To prove: 
  make anothor implemention:
  `public class GenericConverter<E> implements StringConverter<E> {
      public E convert(String value) { return null; }
  }`

  Both `(Class<? extends StringConverter<T>>) GenericConverter.class` and `(Class<? extends StringConverter<?>>) GenericConverter.class` are incorrect.

Comment: This causes a compile error for both IntegerConverter and EnumConverter.

Comment: @BrandonJohnson edit your super interface `Class<? extends StringConverter> getConverter(Class forType);`. If you cannot edit the interface, try @Teemu Ilmonen's answer