# Unable to pass Class parameter for Map

Tags: java, hashmap

I am getting an error in the following line - `Utils.read(new File("asd"),Map<String,Commit>.class);`

The error is `cannot select from parameterized type`
The readObject function is declared as `public static <T extends Serializable> T readObject(File file, Class<T> expectedClass)`
How do I pass a Map of type <String, Commit> in this case

```
The complete definition of readObject function: <br>
 public static <T extends Serializable> T readObject(File file,
                                                        Class<T> expectedClass) {
        try {
            ObjectInputStream in =
                    new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            T result = expectedClass.cast(in.readObject());
            in.close();
            return result;
        } catch (IOException | ClassCastException
                | ClassNotFoundException excp) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(excp.getMessage());
        }
    }<br>
```

Is instead of the above code to read the object, I use the following code :

```
Object readObject(File f) {
        byte[] arr = Utils.readContents(f);
        ByteArrayInputStream i = new ByteArrayInputStream(arr);
        try {
            ObjectInputStream s = new ObjectInputStream(i);
            Object o = s.readObject();
            s.close();
            i.close();
            return o;
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException c) {
            System.out.println("IOException");
            return null;
        }
    }<br>
```

and call `(HashMap<String, Commit>) readObject(Utils.join(dir, "commits"));` Then it works perfectly. The Commit is serializable and internally has a HashMap. This is coming null if I use the earlier code, but it's coming alright with this code. The earlier code I am calling like. ``

Comment: Given the information provided, you could consider just using `Map.class`?

Comment: @BenAnderson That too shows a compilation error `no instance of type variable exists so that map conforms to serializable`

Comment: Using `HashMap.class` works but I am not sure If it will cause some issue as the actual type I am expecting is Map<String,Branch>

Comment: It does cause a problem as Branch is a custom class that internally contains a hashmap. It seems it cannot deserialize this properly

Comment: `Branch` is serializable right?

Comment: And if you can't get your current method to work I'd recommend creating a new map and then deserializing all the objects and adding them to it manually.

Comment: @BenAnderson, yes, the Branch is serializable. I have changed it to `Commit,` which is the same as Branch, and added another code that works well. But not sure why this is not working

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079279/class-object-of-generic-class-java) for some possible work-arounds.